# How to show the view more on my display of pages shortcode

Tags: pages, shortcode, child-pages, get-children

I want to show the list of childpages under a certain parent page & set how many childpages to display & show the "View More" link below the last child page displaying.

What was missing from this code(I just found it) is to display the "View More" in the last childpage of the list. The shortcode used to display is like this:

```
[childpages parentid="1199" display="3" show_viewmore="1"]
```

the `show_viewmore` is not yet applied.

Here is the code now:

```
function rsi_childpages_func($atts, $content = null){
  if($atts['length'] > 0 ){
      //maybe set a minimum length here
  }else{
      $atts['length'] = 50;
  }

  if(isset($atts['parentid']) && is_numeric($atts['parentid'])){
      //id specified by shortcode attribute
      $parent_id = $atts['parentid'];
  }else{
      //get the id of the current article that is calling the shortcode
      $parent_id = get_the_ID();
  }

  if(isset($atts['display']) && is_numeric($atts['display'])){
      $notodisplay = $atts['display'];
  }else{
      $notodisplay = 1;
  }

  if(isset($atts['show_viewmore']) && is_numeric($atts['show_viewmore'])){
      $showviewmore = $atts['show_viewmore'];
  }else{
      $showviewmore = 0;
  }

  $output = "";

  if ( $children = get_children(array(
      'post_parent' => $parent_id,
      'numberposts' => $notodisplay,
      'orderby' => 'menu_order',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'post_type' => 'page')))
  {
      foreach( $children as $child ) {
          $title = $child->post_title;

          $link = get_permalink($child->ID);

          $title = get_the_title($child->ID);

          // OP thumbnail
          $opthumb_url = get_post_meta($child->ID, '_optimizepress_page_thumbnail', true); 
          $rsiicon = get_post_meta($child->ID, 'rsipage_icon', true); 
          $rsidate = get_post_meta($child->ID, 'rsipage_date', true); 
          $opmeta = get_post_meta($child->ID, '_optimizepress_membership', true); 

          $meta = get_post_meta($child->ID);
          $meta = $meta['_'.OP_SN.'_membership'][0];
          $meta = unserialize(unserialize($meta));

          if ($showviewmore = 1){
            $viewmore = '<a href="'. get_permalink($parent_id->ID) .'">Click here to view more of ' . get_the_title($parent_id->ID) .'</a>';
          }

          if ( empty($opthumb_url) ){
            $opthumb_url = 'http://www.memberblueprint.com/salesmastermind/op2/wp-content/themes/optimizePressTheme/lib/images/default-page-listings.png';
          }
          if ($rsiicon != 'blank') {
            $ttd = '<a href="'. $link .'" target="_blank"><img class="alignleft" src="' . $rsiicon . '" width="40" height="40" style="margin:0 5px 10px 10px!important;"/><h6 class="ttitle">'. $title .'</h6><p class="hdate">'. $rsidate .'</p></a>';
          } elseif (!empty($rsidate)) {
            $ttd = '<a href="'. $link .'" target="_blank"><h6 class="ttitle" style="margin-left: 14px;">'. $title .'</h6><p class="hdate" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 15px;">'. $rsidate .'</p></a>';
          } else { 
            $ttd = '<a href="'. $link .'" target="_blank"><h6 class="ttitle" style="margin-left: 14px;">'. $title .'</h6></a>';
          }

          $output .= '<div class="pagelisting">';
          $output .= '<div class="thumb"><a href="'. $link .'" target="_blank"><img src="'. $opthumb_url .'" alt="'. $title .'" class="" width="163"></a></div>' ;
          $output .= '<div class="content">'. $ttd .'';
                        $description = stripslashes(base64_decode($meta['description']));
                        if (strlen($description) > 140) {
                            $output .= '<p class="context">'.substr($description, 0, 140).'...</p>';
                        } else {
                            $output .= '<p class="context">'.$description.'</p>';
                        }
          $output .= '</div>';
          $output .= '<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>'  ;

      }
  } 

  return $output;
}
add_shortcode('childpages', 'rsi_childpages_func');
```

Problem right now, is how can show the "view more" in the last childpage in the list.

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

got it working now...
I added a counter

```
$i = 0;    
$childnum = count($children);
```

just after the if statement of the children. & added this code

```
      if ($i == $childnum - 1) {
          $output .= '<div class="viewmore">'. $viewmore .'</div>';
      }
      $i++;
```

after the the code:

```
$output .= '<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>';
```

...Thanks again.. :)